# Question concerning a list sorting problem

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules, gap

I have the following question:

Let $a,b,c,d$ be four natural numbers with $a \leq b$ and $c\leq d$.

I have written a program that produces a list, which has as entries all 2-tuples $(x,y)$ with $x\in [a..b]$ and $y \in [c..d]$.

Now, I have a new list, let's call it list_1. It consists of elements indexed by the $(x,y)$.

For example, let a=3, b=4, c=7, d=8.

Then my programm produces list=[[3,7],[3,8],[4,7],[4,8]].

Now, my list_1 is [M_{3,7},M_{3,8},M_{4,7},M_{4,8}].

Then I take the direct sum of all modules in list_1 and call this direct sum $M$.

I would like to have a new list, call it list_2, which has exactly all direct summands of $M$ as entries.

In our example, list_2 looks like this:

$[(M_{3,7}),(M_{3,8}),(M_{4,7}),(M_{4,8}),
(M_{3,7}\oplus M_{3,8}),(M_{3,7} \oplus M_{4,7}),(M_{3,7} \oplus M_{4,8}),(M_{3,8} \oplus M_{4,7}),(M_{3,8} \oplus M_{4,8}),(M_{4,7} \oplus M_{4,8}),
(M_{3,7} \oplus M_{3,8} \oplus M_{4,7}),(M_{3,7} \oplus M_{3,8} \oplus M_{4,8}),(M_{3,7} \oplus M_{4,7} \oplus M_{4,8}),(M_{3,8} \oplus M_{4,7} \oplus M_{4,8}),(M_{3,7}\oplus M_{3,8} \oplus M_{4,7} \oplus M_{4,8})]$.

I would like to have this in general for arbitrary natural numbers $a,b,c,d$ with $a \leq b$ and $c\leq d$.

I would be very grateful, if somebody was able to send me a pseudo-code. I would like to implement this in GAP, or, more specifically, with the GAP package qpa.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In Haskell I would do something like

> map plus (tail subsets list_1)

Comment: [Crossposted to cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28997/98).

Comment: In python you have generators that iterate over all tuples of a given size. Perhaps you should switch to SAGE.

Comment: If you generate `list_1` first, you may then use `Combinations` or even `IteratorOfCombinations` (in both cases, remember to exclude empty list) to get what you want. It's interesting though to iterate over `list_2` without intermediate generation of the whole `list_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my former comment, first we create a cartesian product of ranges:

```
gap> list1:=Cartesian([3..4],[7..8]);
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
```

Then we may enumerate all non-empty combinations of `k` elements of `list1` as follows:

```
gap> for k in [1..Length(list1)] do
>      iter:=IteratorOfCombinations(list1,k);
>      for c in iter do
>        Print(c,"\n");
>      od;
>    od;
[ [ 3, 7 ] ]
[ [ 3, 8 ] ]
[ [ 4, 7 ] ]
[ [ 4, 8 ] ]
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 3, 8 ] ]
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 4, 7 ] ]
[ [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 7 ] ]
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
[ [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
[ [ 4, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 7 ] ]
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 4, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
[ [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
[ [ 3, 7 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ] ]
```

Hope it should be now easy to adapt this code to perform calculations that you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works perfectly fine. :-)

Comment: Great, thanks! Note that the QPA package is not (yet?) redistributed with GAP. Hope to see it deposited one day, that would also imply that it will be better tested for compatibility with GAP and other packages.